# Equivalent of `newdateformat` in `datetime2`?

Tags: packages, datetime

The [`datetime`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime?lang=en) package has recently been withdrawn and replaced by [`datetime2`](ftp://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/datetime2.html). Any idea for the equivalent of `newdateformat` in `datetime2` ?

Comment: `\DTMnewdatestyle`?

Comment: Could you make your question more specific?

Answer (score 9):

With `datetime`, a new date format was defined using

```
\newdateformat{〈name〉}{〈format〉}
```

Within 〈format〉you could use `\THEDAY`, `\THEMONTH` and `\THEYEAR` to reference the day, month and year number. You could also use `\twodigit` to convert a number to two digits. For example:

```
\newdateformat{dashdate}{%
  \twodigit{\THEDAY}-\twodigit{\THEMONTH}-\THEYEAR}
```

With the new `datetime2` package, a new date format is defined using:

```
\DTMnewdatestyle{〈name〉}{〈definition〉}
```

Here the 〈definition〉part should redefine the two commands `\DTMdisplaydate` and `\DTMDisplaydate`. Both these commands have four arguments which represent the year, month, day and day of week numbers. If the day of week number is -1 the style should ignore it, but a style may also ignore the day of week regardless of its value. Instead of `\twodigits`, we now have `\DTMtwodigits` which will display its (numerical) argument with exactly two digits. (So it will add a leading zero if the absolute value is less than 10 or it will trim a number if the absolute value is greater than 99.) There are also two other commands you might find useful when defining a date style: `\DTMcentury` and `\DTMdivhundred`. There was no direct equivalent in the old `datetime` package for those two commands.

So to convert our old `dashdate` example to the new `datetime2` format:

```
\DTMnewdatestyle{dashdate}{%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\DTMtwodigits{##3}-\DTMtwodigits{##2}-##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
```

Here `##3` is the third argument of `\DTMdisplaydate` (the day), `##2` is the second argument of `\DTMdisplaydate` (the month) and `##1` is the first argument of `\DTMdisplaydate` (the year). The fourth argument is ignored. Since the date style is numeric `\DTMDisplaydate` is set to the same as `\DTMdisplaydate` as the style is the same regardless of whether or not a date occurs at the start of a sentence.

If you want a textual date style, you can use additional commands provided by the relevant language module. For example, if you have loaded the [English module](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english) you can use commands such as `\DTMenglishmonthname` or `\DTMenglishordinal`. (These commands are described in the "Base Code (datetime2-english-base.ldf)" section of the [module's documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2-contrib/datetime2-english/datetime2-english.pdf).)

So the `datetime` manual's example:

```
\newdateformat{usvardate}{%
  \monthname[\THEMONTH] \ordinaldate{\THEDAY}, \THEYEAR}
```

can be converted to `datetime2` using:

```
\DTMnewdatestyle{usvardate}{%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\DTMenglishmonthname{##2} \DTMenglishordinal{##3}, ##1}%
  \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
```

This style will only work if the `datetime2-english` module is loaded otherwise the commands `\DTMenglishmonthname` and `\DTMenglishordinal` will be undefined. Since English month names always start with a capital letter, `\DTMDisplaydate` is again set to `\DTMdisplaydate`. For languages where this isn't the case then `\DTMDisplaydate` would need to start with a capital letter. For example, with the `datetime2-french` module, you can use `\DTMfrenchMonthname` for the month name starting with a capital and `\DTMfrenchmonthname` for the lower case month name.

Finally, with `datetime`, `\newdateformat{〈name〉}{〈format〉}` created a command called `\〈name〉` (so `\dashdate` in the first example and `\usvardate` in the second example) which can be used to switch to that format, but with `datetime2` the date format is set using `\DTMsetdatestyle{〈name〉}` (so `\DTMsetdatestyle{dashdate}` in the first example and `\DTMsetdatestyle{usvardate}` in the second example).

Comment: @Peter says: "Correction to code block: '\DTMtwodigit' should be '\DTMtwodigits'"