# Changing the format of \today to Month year

Tags: date

I want `\date{\today}` to show the date in the format Month-year; without the day (i.e: July 2023), instead of: day of the week-day-Month, year (i.e.: Tuesday 18th July, 2023).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used some information from the `datetime2` manual and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251829/123129).

- define a new date style `monthyear` (using `\DTMnewdatestyle`)
- set the style with `\DTMsetdatestyle{monthyear}`

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\DTMnewdatestyle{monthyear}{%
    % ##1 = year, ##2 = month, ##3 = day
    \renewcommand*{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\DTMenglishmonthname{##2} ##1}%
    \renewcommand*{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}

\begin{document}
\DTMsetdatestyle{monthyear}
This PDF was created on \today.
\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package datetime provides the function ,,longdate'':

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{datetime}

\begin{document}
    Today is:  \longdate \today
\end{document}
```

> Today is: Tuesday 18th July, 2023

Comment: I'm not seeing how that answers the question.

Comment: sorry, i mistook the format

Comment: For the format in question simply write:  \monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR